# Cubic equation solution

Tags: equation-solving

Writing:

```
eqn = x^3 + c2 x^2 + c1 x + c0 == 0;
ass = {c2 -> 3, c1 -> 3, c0 -> 3};
sol = Assuming[c1 == c2^2/3, Simplify[Solve[eqn, x]]] /. ass;
eqn /. ass /. sol // FullSimplify
```

I get:

> {False, False, False}

and I can't understand why! Ideas? Thank you!

Comment: For a start, in the first case your assumptions in `Assuming` have no effect, because the result of `Solve` does not contain `c1` or `c2`, since you have replaced them with explicit numerical values by doing `eqn /. ass`.

Comment: The Cardano-Tartaglia form of solution is not valid for that set of substitution values (it makes numerator and denominator vanish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it you are substituting your values too late.  It works if the substitution occurs before it tries to solve.

```
eqn = x^3 + c2 x^2 + c1 x + c0 == 0;

ass = {c2 -> 3, c1 -> 3, c0 -> 3};

sol = Solve[eqn /. ass, x]
(*{{x -> -1 - 2^(1/3)}, {x -> -1 + (1 - I Sqrt[3])/2^(
    2/3)}, {x -> -1 + (1 + I Sqrt[3])/2^(2/3)}}*)

sol = Solve[eqn, x]
```

Gives you a solution, but when you substitute your values you get indeterminates.  Taking limits may help, but the problem is avoided by making the substitution first.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's much more robust to use [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root) objects instead of radicals. If you do that with your example, there is no issue:

```
eqn = x^3+c2 x^2+c1 x+c0==0;
ass = {c2->3,c1->3,c0->3};
sol = Assuming[c1==c2^2/3,
    Simplify[Solve[eqn, x, Cubics->False]]
] /. ass;
eqn /.ass/. sol //FullSimplify
```

> {True, True, True}